# Is there a Windows client for Tumblr?

Tags: windows-7, tumblr

I would love to be able to write my posts on a windows client instead of the crappy textarea box thingy. Is there a Windows client for Tumblr? Something like Live Writer (which for some reason supports EVERY other major platform other than Tumblr)

I am currently evaluating [WinTumblr](http://wintumblr.tumblr.com/)

Comment: Or more accurately, every major platform besides Tumblr supports standard blogging protocols, which Live Writer implements.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty exhaustive list [provided by Tumblr](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/apps). Looks like the only one applicable to you is [OpenTumblr](http://code.google.com/p/opentumblr/downloads/list).

Answer (score 0):

Not really. But...there are a few other solutions:

- **Use Ping.fm**: there's a plugin for Live Writer that posts to [Ping.fm](http://ping.fm), which you can then [link to Tumblr](http://ping.fm/tumblr/).  <sup>[(source)](http://starrbrite.com/blog/2011/how-to-use-windows-live-writer-to-post-to-tumblr/)</sup>

If that doesn't work for you, try these:

- **Copy-pasting**: you can copy-paste your blog entry into Tumblr's textarea thingy, from say, Word. Unfortunately that's another step to do, but I'm sure someday somebody will write up a script that'll do it for you.
- **Use Posterous**: somebody is going to kill me for suggesting this, but you can always use Posterous's autopost feature to [link Live Writer](http://writerous.codeplex.com/) to tumblr.